# Orientability of Ringed Space

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, sheaf-theory, smooth-manifolds, ringed-spaces

Differential manifold can be defined in two ways. **One definition** is a topological space equipped with an atlas and transition maps. **Another definition** is a topological space equipped with a sheaf of functions.

Using first definition orientability of manifold means all Jacobians are positive.

How to define orientable manifold using second definition?

Comment: I suspect that it should be a sheaf-theoretic translation of the criterion that the $C^\infty(X)$-module $\Omega^n(X)$ is free (of rank $1$), where $n = \dim X$.

Comment: @Branimir: $\Omega^{n}(X)$ is differential $n-$forms? Globally free?

Comment: Differential $n$-forms, i.e., global sections of $\wedge^n T^\ast X$, which form a finitely-generated projective $C^\infty(X)$-module; a volume form, then, or rather the singleton set containing it, is the same thing as a basis presenting $\Omega^n(X)$ as a free $C^\infty(X)$-module of rank $1$. I suppose the better perspective for you is that $\wedge^n T^\ast X$ is globally free of rank $1$.